# Forms of address between couples

Tags: second-person-pronouns

I've come to understand that middle aged women may refer to their husbands as あなた when talking to them. If a wife is talking to a friend or work colleague, how would she refer to her husband?

Also for younger people around school/university age, would 君【きみ】 be used as a similar thing for a girlfriend to refer to her boyfriend? If not what would be?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/48866/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43849/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how could she refer to her husband. (Just curious)

（うちの）だんな (colloquial)

（私の）主人 (formal)

> would 君きみ be used as a similar thing for a girlfriend to refer to her boyfriend?

Yes. It's possible.

> If not what would be?

〇〇君（くん）　（〇〇 is his first name)